# How to get the pointcut details in the aspect constructor

Tags: java, java-8, aspectj

I have a an annotation style aspect which is something like that:

```
//....
//somewhere in another class
//
@MyAnnotation 
public void foo(){ \* does stuff *\}
/////////////////////

// in the aspect file
@Aspect("percflow(execution(@com.bla.MyAnnotation * *(..)))")
public class MyAspect {
    public MyAspect(){
         /* Here I'd like to access the name of the annotated function e.g: foo*/ 
    }
    /* more pointcuts and advice*/
}
```

I've tried capturing the object with `this(Object)` but this didn't do any good.
I've also tried introducing a parameter to the constructor but that just caused an error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is actually not necessary to do anything in the constructor. You can just declare the pointcut within `percflow()` as a stand-alone object and use it within `percflow()` as well as in a `@Before` advice which, as the instantiation model implies, will only be executed once and gives you all necessary information via the corresponding `JoinPoint` object. You can now log or store the information as you fancy.

BTW, idea of using a constructor is not so nice because within the constructor the aspect instance is not initialised yet (hen vs. egg problem) and will cause exceptions when trying to access it.

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.app;

public class Application {
    public void doSomething() {}

    @MyAnnotation
    public String repeatText(int times, String text) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < times; i++)
            result += text;
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application application = new Application();
        application.doSomething();
        application.repeatText(3, "andale ");
    }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;

@Aspect("percflow(myPointcut())")
public class MyAspect {
    @Pointcut("execution(@de.scrum_master.app.MyAnnotation * *(..))")
    private static void myPointcut() {}

    @Before("myPointcut()")
    public void myAdvice(JoinPoint thisJoinPoint) {
        System.out.println(thisJoinPoint);
        System.out.println("  " + thisJoinPoint.getSignature().getName());
        for (Object arg : thisJoinPoint.getArgs())
            System.out.println("    " + arg);
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
execution(String de.scrum_master.app.Application.repeatText(int, String))
  repeatText
    3
    andale
```